# how to submit inputs to a handler methods in razor pages?

Tags: c#, forms, asp.net-core, handler, razor-pages

I am using razor pages I have 2 inputs dates:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Filters.From" value="@Model.Filters.From.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" />
<input type="hidden" asp-for="Filters.To" value="@Model.Filters.To.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" />

<a asp-page-handler="Export" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="border-color: inherit">
    Export
</a>
```

I want to submit the inputs to a GET method named OnGetExport

```
public IActionResult OnGetExport(CustomersPayload filter)
{
  return Page();
}
```

payload:

```
public class CustomersPayload 
{ 
public DateTime From { get; set; } 
public DateTime To { get; set; } }
}
```

How can I can I call this OnGetExport method with those 2 input payload with using anchor tag?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `asp-route-xxx` to pass data to `OnGetExport` with anchor tag:

```
<a asp-page-handler="Export" class="btn btn-primary" type="button" style="border-color: inherit" asp-route-From="@Model.Filters.From.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")" asp-route-To="@Model.Filters.To.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd")">
        Export
    </a>
```

result:
[image]